# How to use NSURLResponse as segue trigger swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

I'm doing this in my project.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.12345.biz/BpjsHost/NonTransactionManager/ValidateAccount")!)
    request.setValue(apikey, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) in

        let postString = ("msisdn=\(userMsisdn!)")
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("error = \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

and this is the response:

```
responseString = {"id":"9082","groupID":"13","status":"PROCESSED","msisdn":"085959981892","name":"Prio","cf_partner_id":null}
```

How to use the response status which is "PROCESSED" as trigger to perform segue to another view controller.

Comment: transfer  data to a `Dictionary` by `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` then check it with something like `responseDict["status"] == "PROCESSED" `

Answer (score 1):

On the closure that handles the response from your request, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
//- after your guard error = nil ...
do {
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary {

        if let status = json["status"] as! String {
            if (status == "PROCESSED"){
                //- this is still in a separate thread
                //- lets go back to the main thread!
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    //- this happens in the main thread
                    performSegueWithIdentifier("blahblah", sender: self)
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
              //handle error
    }
```

This will serialize the response into a dictionary, so we can then unwrap its "status" member and invoke the segue in the main thread. Its important to remember to execute the segue in the main thread as your completion handler will perform its task in a separate thread.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd suggest `as?` rather than `as!`. I'd also suggest `==` rather than `===`.

Comment: Thanks! forgot this is not js =D

Comment: Hi @DanielOrmeño I got this [error](https://postimg.org/image/tokc7hb6f/) what did I miss?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a catch statement after the do!

Comment: I edited the code block! Sorry it was a bit ambiguous

Comment: No problem! happy to help